# Need help with vectors and the dot product

Tags: calculus, vectors

I've got a homework question:
$\vec{a} = \vec{i} + 2 \vec{j} + t \vec{k},$
$\vec{b} = 3 \vec{i} + 2 \vec{j} + \vec{k}$

Find $t$ such that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular to each other.

I assume I have to use the dot product to find if the vectors are perpendicular to each other, and I end up with $t = 7$. Was wondering if this is correct and if i'm on the right path. Cheers!

Comment: The dot product should be $0$. Check your work again. I believe it is just a careless mistake.

Comment: the answer should be $t=-7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 1*3 + 2*2 + t*1 = 7 + t$

The vectors are perpendicular when the dot product equals zero. Therefore, $t = -7$.

Comment: Thankyou! as a follow up, when using the cross product on a and b (say w = a x b) what will the resulting vector look like given the scaler t?

Comment: Well, you can substitute $t$ before or after calculating the cross product. If you dont know how to calculate it you can choose a method to your liking from the ones explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).